# Two ViewModels in one "details" fragment

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

I have three fragments, the first `ListFragment` it's a `Recyclerview` contains all documents of firebase collection, the second `FavoritesFragment` it's `Recyclerview` of favorites items chosen by the user from the first `Recyclerview`. and the third `DetailsFragment` that shows the details of the item that clicked from one of this two recyclerviews. i use navigation component in my app, and MVVM architecture.

My question is: can i add two viewmodels, one for BlockListViewModel and one for BlockListFavViewModel to `DetailsFragment` in `onActivityCreated` to get the appropriate position of recyclerview data from firebase, because with this code at the bottom i can get the correct position if the user comes from the `ListFragment`, and wrong if user comes from `FavoritesFragment`.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        blockListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(BlockListViewModel.class);
        blockListViewModel.getBlockListModelData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<BlockListModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<BlockListModel> blockListModels) {

                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(blockListModels.get(position).getImage())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                        .into(detailsImage);

                matTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getMat());
                finishedTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getFinished());
                cutTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getCut());
                assembleTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getAssemble());

                blockId = blockListModels.get(position).getBlock_id();
                blockTitle = blockListModels.get(position).getName();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think you can only have one ViewModel?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Because I am new to android :) .. but my question is how i can use specific viewmodel if the user comes from specific fragment and use the other viewmodel if the user comes from the second fragment. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm sharing coding part how you implement in your code

Call DetailFragment From ListFragment :

```
DetailFragment detailFrm = new DetailFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("OpenFrom", "ListFragment");
detailFrm.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, detailFrm).commit();
```

Call DetailFragment From FavoritesFragment :

```
DetailFragment detailFrm = new DetailFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("OpenFrom", "FavoritesFragment");
detailFrm.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, detailFrm).commit();
```

In DetailFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
String value = getArguments().getString("OpenFrom");
if(value.equals("ListFragment"){

//use First Viewmodel
        blockListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(BlockListViewModel.class);
        blockListViewModel.getBlockListModelData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<BlockListModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<BlockListModel> blockListModels) {

                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(blockListModels.get(position).getImage())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                        .into(detailsImage);

                matTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getMat());
                finishedTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getFinished());
                cutTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getCut());
                assembleTXT.setText(blockListModels.get(position).getAssemble());

                blockId = blockListModels.get(position).getBlock_id();
                blockTitle = blockListModels.get(position).getName();
            }
        });
        }else if(value.equals("FavoritesFragment"){
        
          //use Other Viewmodel     
        }
    }
```

If you have any query you can ask me.

Comment: Thank You @webaddicted, it works, I made a slight change when passing the OpenFrom value because I am using navigation component in my app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of use two viewmodel, if this is requirement of you're project to use to view model.
Then you can seperate use of viewmodel in detail fragment by passing veriable from ListFragment and FavoritesFragment,
If fragment open from  ListFragment then send classname as TAG, same for FavoritesFragment, and in detailFragment check that veriable,
on the bases of that variable use viewmodel.

Comment: This what i want, please can you show me how to do it programmatically, thank you!